# How can I rebuild tern_for_vim's index of my code?

Tags: plugin-ternjs

I am using tern_for_vim to provide javascript support on autocompletion, jump to definitions and it also generates hints about parameter type based on any JSDocs I write for my functions. 
The problem is if I update those JSDocs, tern doesnt seem to update its defintions.
Is it possible to tell tern to reload / reparse my code?

Answer (score 1):

According ["Tern for Vim" plugin](https://github.com/marijnh/tern_for_vim)  homepage,

> This is a Vim plugin that provides Tern-based JavaScript editing support.

So it is an easier interface for the [Tern](http://ternjs.net/) tool. Therefore, if you don't find the information on how to update the index on the [plugin documentation](https://github.com/marijnh/tern_for_vim/blob/master/doc/tern.txt), you should check the [Tern documentation](http://ternjs.net/doc/manual.html).

I can't point the direct command/configuration, as I don't use JavaScript nor Tern; but you probably executed it to generate a first version of the definition list, otherwise it wouldn't have worked at all. If it is a configuration, maybe it just became outdated (for instance, if you moved the project directory). If it is a command you can create a mapping to make it easier to trigger the update.

Answer (score 0):

this is embarrasing, but it seems the failure to update was because my JSDoc code wasnt syntactically correct.
Once I fixed my doc comments - the autocomplete hints updated automatically.
It seems the tern server doesnt need to be manually reloaded as you would with a ctags file for example.  I think the interaction between vim and tern occurs regularly - perhaps everytime you invoke a tern command or autocompletion...?